# Background When Exporting Power BI Dashboard to PDF

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to export a tab I created in Power BI to PDF. My tab has a black background but when I export it, a thin white line is present at the top and bottom of the PDF. Otherwise is looks fine. Any idea why this would be happening?

Comment: this the native padding that PowerBI adds - there is no way to change it unless you export to PPT then remove the padding your self. I had a requirement from a client a while back to export a "pretty" looking PDF from dynamic PBI data. I eventually exported it and wrote a python program using `python-pptx` which works by editing the underlying xml

Comment: Got it, thank you for your help!